# Unable to acquire JDBC Connection in SpringBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Microservices‑Based Application, each Microservice is a SpringBoot 2.0.3.RELEASE app., but after my 4rth Microservices launched I have this error:

```
    Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
..
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

I would like to know how to reduce the `maximumPoolSize` or if there is a way to know `maximumPoolSize` because I have't seen anything related when the app starts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the maximum pool size of the JDBC connections in your `application.properties` file like:

`spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5`